# java String.replaceAll regex question

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a string that contains the following text

```
String my_string = "hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr! br br";
```

I'd like to replace each *isolated* **br** with `<br />`

The issue is that I'd like to avoid converting the string to

```
"hello world. it's cold out <br />rrrrr! <br /> <br />";
```

What I'd like to do is convert the string (using replaceAll) to

```
"hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr! <br /> <br />";
```

I'm sure this is very simple, but my regex isn't correct.

```
my_string.replaceAll("\\sbr\\s|\\sbr$", "<br />");
```

my regex is *supposed* to find 'whitespace' 'b' 'r' 'whitespace' OR 'whitespace' 'b' 'r' 'end of line'

but it misses the final "br" in my string

```
"hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<br />br"
```

what am I doing wrong?? TKS!

Comment: `"hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<br />br"
` Your final 'br' isn't preceded by whitespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
my_string.replaceAll("\\bbr\\b", "<br />");
```

---

Your regex doesn't work because in

```
␣br␣br
^
```

The pattern `\sbr\s` will consume the whole `␣br␣`, leaving with

```
<br />br
      ^
```

now there is no preceding space for this `br` to match `\sbr$`, so it will be missed.

On the other hand, the `\b`, meaning a word-boundary, is a zero-width assertion, i.e. it won't consume any characters. Therefore the spaces will be kept and all isolated `br`'s will be matched.

Comment: ok, so let me see if i get this straight... \b is word boundary, right?  and apparently it works on "end of line" too?

Comment: The end of a line is a word boundary if the last character in the line is a word character:.  More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @Tony: [not reproducible](http://www.ideone.com/rcxNC). What kind of Java are you using?

Comment: Comment deleted. I didn't notice the OP's string didn't meet his own criteria about leading whitespace.

Comment: @KennyTM, what happens if you use "hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<br />br" as an input string?  I still get a bad result... `hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<<br /> /><br />'

Comment: Latest JVM, yadda.  Code is:   String myString = "hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<br />br";
        System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("\\bbr\\b", "<br />"));

Comment: @Tony: This is because `<` and `b` form a word boundary. Since OP doesn't specify what to do in this case, I don't think it is a "bad" result.

Comment: @KennyTM - You are correct - it is undefined.  But do you think nesting a break statement inside of angle brackets is a desirable result?  You can just about guess what the OP's _next_ question will be, heh.  This shows how difficult it can be to do any manipulation of HTML using regexp.

Comment: @KennyTM. Thank you. I didn't realize there was a concept of "consumption"

Comment: And maybe you should add `.replaceAll("\\bout\\b", "outside")`.

Answer (score 0):

`"hello world. it's cold out brrrrrr!<br />br"` Your final 'br' isn't preceded by whitespace.  What's supposed to happen?